# Prism Dependent Modules

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

This should be an easy one,

I have a `DomainModule` and a `ServicesModule` where `DomainModule` uses `ServicesModule`.

```
DomainModule --> ServicesModule
```

**Module's definitions :**

```
    [ModuleDependency("ServicesModule")]
    [Module(ModuleName = "DomainModule")]    
    public class DomainModule : ModuleBase
...

[Module(ModuleName = "ServicesModule")]
public class ServicesModule : ModuleBase
```

**The error I'm getting :**

> *A module declared a dependency on another module which is not declared to be loaded. Missing module(s): ServicesModule*

Not sure that if I add a reference to the `ServicesModule` will I lose the loose coupling rule or not, but I tried not to do that, If I'm wrong on this tell me please.

What is your suggestions/hints on this ?

Comment: Sorry, but the pieces of answer were old and didn't work for me, some of the statements were for 2008 versions and prior which they were totally changed, thanks for the help provided yet. Still looking for a good working solution around this.

Answer (score 1):

The current release of the Composite Application Library do not bring support for loading modules on demand with dependencies.

But there is a workaround to this by creating an `extension method to load the dependent modules` which can be found [here](http://blogs.southworks.net/mconverti/2008/11/13/how-to-load-modules-on-demand-that-have-dependencies-using-composite-wpf-prism/).

Comment: While I was studying Prism's documents, I could remember there was some loading options or we could give them some priorities, Am I wrong ?! Also do you recommend adding the "Services Module" as a reference ? Which one could be better here, do the trick you mentioned or Adding a reference, Any Alternates or options ? thanks

Comment: I would suggest instead of adding a direct reference, try the extesnion method approach which was also suggested at `MSDN` here - http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/39319

Comment: Priority approch you can also try - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296642/how-to-control-the-order-of-module-initialization-in-prism