# Problems with module dependency and eventAggregator on module load in C# prism

Tags: c#, wpf, module, prism, eventaggregator

i using prism with c# an there i have a problem with the load of two modules. In module A is a TabControl with a ItemTemplate and ContentTemplate. Module B is a Subview of module A and is in the ContentTemplate of Module A.

**Xaml of Module A**

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ListModulRegion" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel of Module A**

In the ViewModel of Module A is a eventAggregator. Which publish a event when a other item in the TabControll is selected.

```
    #region Private Fields **************************************************************************************************

    private readonly IDeviceService _deviceService;
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    private ModuleFolder _selectedItem;
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties ***********************************************************************************************

    public IEnumerable<ModuleFolder> Folders
    {
        get
        {
            return _deviceService.ModuleFolders;
        }
    }

    public ModuleFolder SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
            ModuleFolderChangeEvent evt = _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ModuleFolderChangeEvent>();
            evt.Publish(SelectedItem);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor(s) **************************************************************************************************

    public FolderSelectionViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IDeviceService deviceService)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        _deviceService = deviceService;
        if(_deviceService.ModuleFolders.Count>0)
        {
            SelectedItem = _deviceService.ModuleFolders[0];
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel of Module B**

In the ViewModel of Module B the eventAggregator is subscribte to this event.

```
    #region Private Fields **************************************************************************************************
    private ModuleFolder _currentFolder;
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private readonly IDeviceService _deviceService;
    private readonly IUiDispatcher _uiDispatcher;

    private ObservableCollection<ModuleViewModel> _observableModules;
    private ModuleViewModel _selectedListItem;
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties ***********************************************************************************************

    public ObservableCollection<ModuleViewModel> ObservableModules
    {
        get
        {
            return (_observableModules);
        }
        set
        {
            _observableModules = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => ObservableModules);
        }
    }

    public ModuleViewModel SelectedListItem
    {
        get { return _selectedListItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedListItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedListItem);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor(s) **************************************************************************************************

    public ModuleListViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IUiDispatcher uiDispatcher, IDeviceService deviceService)
    {
        ModuleFolderChangeEvent evt = eventAggregator.GetEvent<ModuleFolderChangeEvent>();
        evt.Subscribe(OnMailFolderChanged);

        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        _uiDispatcher = uiDispatcher;
        _deviceService = deviceService;

        PropertyChanged += ModuleListSelectionViewModel_PropertyChanged;
    }
    #endregion
```

**Bootstrapper**

In the Bootsrapper module A depends on  modul B.

```
    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
    {
        base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();

        ModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = (ModuleCatalog) ModuleCatalog;

        //Communication
        Type serviceModule = typeof(CommunicationModule);
        moduleCatalog.AddModule(serviceModule);

        //Device List
        Type deviceListUiModule = typeof(DeviceListModule);
        System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<string> dependsDeviceListUi = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<string>
        {
            serviceModule.Name
        };

        moduleCatalog.AddModule(new ModuleInfo
        {
            ModuleName = deviceListUiModule.Name,
            ModuleType = deviceListUiModule.AssemblyQualifiedName,
            DependsOn = dependsDeviceListUi,
        });

        //Tap Region
        Type selectionUiModule = typeof (SelectionModule);
        System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<string> dependsSelectionUi = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<string>
        {
            serviceModule.Name,
            deviceListUiModule.Name
        };

        moduleCatalog.AddModule(new ModuleInfo
        {
            ModuleName = selectionUiModule.Name,
            ModuleType = selectionUiModule.AssemblyQualifiedName,
            DependsOn = dependsSelectionUi
        });
    }
```

**The Problem**

When module A is loaded. The first item is selected and publish an event. But module B is not loaded an subscribe to late to the event an miss the first publish. At the second time when module B is loaded every thing works fine.

I have read about [How to control the order of module initialization in Prism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296642/how-to-control-the-order-of-module-initialization-in-prism). But maybe there is another way or better way of doing that. Because i'm new in prism and i dont now the best way to doing it.

Sorry for my poor english. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Within the bootstrap process ensure "ModuleB" gets loaded and initialized before "ModuleA".

Comment: How can i do that?

Because module B is the Device List which is added before module A(Tab Region). And there is also a dependency.