# Multiple DirectoryModuleCatalog in a Prism application

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism

We have Unity+Prism WPF applications, and there is 2 folders from which we want to load dynamically the modules.

I know that to load modules from a directory, I should use a `DirectoryModuleCatalog`, but the `CreateModuleCatalog` method allows only one catalog to be returned, so how do I wrap them in one catalog?

In my boostrapper, what should I return here:

```
    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = @".\Services" };
        new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = @".\Packages" };
        //Maybe some day another catalog, maybe not even a directory one.

        return ???????;
    }
```

According to @Haukinger, I should develop my own catalog, so I started with this:

```
public class AggregatedModuleCatalog : IModuleCatalog
{

    private readonly List<IModuleCatalog> _catalogs;
    private readonly ModuleCatalog _localModulesCatalog = new ModuleCatalog();

    public IEnumerable<ModuleInfo> Modules => _catalogs.SelectMany(c => c.Modules).ToList();

    public AggregatedModuleCatalog(IReadOnlyCollection<IModuleCatalog> catalogs)
    {
        if (catalogs == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        _catalogs = new List<IModuleCatalog>(_catalogs) {_localModulesCatalog};
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModuleInfo> GetDependentModules(ModuleInfo moduleInfo)
    {
        return _catalogs.SelectMany(c => c.GetDependentModules(moduleInfo)).Distinct().ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModuleInfo> CompleteListWithDependencies(IEnumerable<ModuleInfo> modules)
    {
        return _catalogs.SelectMany(c => c.CompleteListWithDependencies(modules)).Distinct().ToList();
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _catalogs.ForEach(c => c.Initialize());
    }

    public void AddModule(ModuleInfo moduleInfo)
    {
        _localModulesCatalog.AddModule(moduleInfo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to write an `AggregatingModuleCatalog` that implements `IModuleCatalog` and receives several other `IModuleCatalog`s and its implementation somehow delegates to the inner catalogs.

Probably easier to clone the `DirectoryModuleCatalog` and make it look in multiple directories. The old [SmartDirectoryModuleCatalog](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=prismextensions) might be a good starting point, too.

Comment: Really? I'm the first one needing this?

Comment: There will be a problem if a dependency is only in `_localModules`, because your `CompleteWithDependencies` won't find it. Same for `GetDependentModules`... better store the local modules in a local `ModuleCatalog` instead of a `List`. Also, I'd make `_catalogs` a `IReadOnlyCollection`, otherwise you potentially get a different set of catalogs each time you enumerate them.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution works for in Prism 8. Let me know if it helps you.

```
protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
{
     var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
     var directories = new string[]{"Modules", "Services" };

     List<IModuleCatalogItem> components = new List<IModuleCatalogItem>();

     foreach (var dir in directories)
     {
         var dirCatelog = new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = $"{path}\\{dir}" };
         dirCatelog.Initialize();

         components.AddRange(dirCatelog.Items);
     }

     var catelog = new ModuleCatalog();

     foreach (var com in components)
     {
         catelog.Items.Add(com);
     }

     return catelog;
}
```